# Why does cloud functions return ‘Optional()’ with the value

Tags: javascript, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function to check wether an email is in use or not, here’s the code for the function:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()

exports.uniqueEmail = functions.https.onCall((data) => {

  const email = data.email;
  if (!email) {
    console.log('missing email')
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Missing email parameter');
  }
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email).then(function(userRecord) {
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
    return "true"
  }).catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
   console.log('Email: ', email)
   return "false"
  });
});
```

As you can see, the function does work, it knows wether the email is taken or not, however it gives my app back “Optional(false)” instead of “false” or “true”.

Here’s my Xcode code:

```
IBAction func nextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        var result = ""
        if(emailInputField.text != ""){
            Functions.functions().httpsCallable("uniqueEmail").call(["email": emailInputField.text]) { (result, error) in
                if let error = error as NSError? {
                    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
                        let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                        let message = error.localizedDescription
                        let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
                    }
                    // ...
                }
                    print(result?.data)
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is because the function may or may not return a result, as it may or may not return an error; therefore, they must be optional and thus must be unwrapped. And so simply unwrap the result object just like you unwrapped the error object.

Comment: @bsod could you put your comment as an answer so there’s more detail and so I can mark it as as answered when I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get opcional(true/false because) you're printing an optional value '?'

your code:

```
print(result?.data)
```

example:

```
let value = false

print("this is a false value: \(value?)")
```

everytime you print a value with '?' you'll get opcional first

Answer (score 0):

The callback you pass to [call()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefunctions/api/reference/Classes/HTTPSCallable#callcompletion:) yields either a HTTPSCallableResult or an Error:

> ```
> func call(completion: @escaping (HTTPSCallableResult?, Error?) -> Void)
> ```

Either one might be nil, which is why you have to check them **both** before using their values.  You're checking `error` right now, but you're not checking `result`, which means you're getting an Optional that needs further checks for nil.

You should instead use a pattern as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function):

```
functions.httpsCallable("addMessage").call(["text": inputField.text]) { (result, error) in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
      let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
      let message = error.localizedDescription
      let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
    }
    // ...
  }
  if let text = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["text"] as? String {
    self.resultField.text = text
  }
}
```

Notice that `if let` is used in both error and success cases.

Comment: I’ve done that, however all the results are being given back as ‘nil’

Comment: It sounds like `if let` actually worked for you after all.